# Git from China?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

What's the best way to get Git to work from China? Heroku to be exact. My internet speed is decent, 8+mb download, 1mb upload. But even something like Git Pull will 'hang up unexpectedly'. Most websites load fine though.

Comment: Can you change and transfer via HTTP?  Take a look at: http://book.git-scm.com/7_transfer_protocols.html

Answer (score 3):

Good. It seems you've crashed onto the Great Firewall (GFW for short) ;-)

When you mean most websites load fine, can you access twitter/facebook/youtube? If you see "connection reset by peer" then that's it.

Use a VPN or SSH tunnel to send your network traffic through the GFW is a common option to bypass censorship.

I myself setup my own homebrew ssh tunnel/VPN on [linode VPS](http://linode.com). There are many VPN service providers, [one](http://yegle.net/openvpn/) build by [@yegle](http://twitter.com/yegle) is pretty decent. One of my friends just setup a [new site](http://vpnst.com/), you might want to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Using VPN is a good choice. I have using Shadowsocks for serval months. It works fine.

Comment: Please put some effort in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Haha this is a common problem for foreign folks all around here.

Yeah Shadowsocks is great, since VPN protocols can be easily detected by the authority (secret: some people are charged crime for this.)

Maybe you should setup a server in Hong Kong with Shadowsocks server configured. But one temporary solution is local mapping.

Modify your system hosts file and map the address `43.242.175.186` to the `git` server hostname.

Personally I’d prefer Alibaba Cloud.

Comment: 43.242.175.186 is a SNI Proxy located in Hong Kong